# Redux and long running asynchronous tasks

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, websocket, redux-thunk

I have a React SPA, where Redux backs up my state. I want to submit a long-running task to the server and get periodic updates (say a loading bar or just plain text). Communication is done via WebSockets. What is the recommended way I structure this architecturally in Redux?

Let's add some code for clarity, with the `TODO` being where I don't know what to do

```
// Render 

<LoadingBar show={this.props.showLoadingBar} progress={this.props.progress} /> // From redux store connect
<button onClick={store.dispatch(startLongRunningProcess())} />

// Action

function startLongRunningProcess() {
    // TODO: Should I open my web socket here?
    return {
        action: START_LONG_RUNNING_PROCESS,
        payload: null,
    }
}

// Reducer

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case START_LONG_RUNNING_PROCESS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            showLoadingBar: true,
        }
    }
    // TODO: Where do I dispatch this guy?
    case FINISH_LONG_RUNNING_PROCESS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            showLoadingBar: false,
        }
    }
    // TODO: Where do I dispatch this guy?
    case PROGRESS_UPDATE_FROM_SERVER: {
        return {
            ...state,
            progress: action.payload.progress,
        }
    }
};
```

I am happy to add more libraries (maybe `redux-thunk`) to my dependency list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you're not forced to use `redux-thunk` or a library like that. Just import your store wherever you're using your websockets, and call `store.dispatch` with the action you use to update the store. That should be enough in your case.